# haw I can write long equation in Latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, arrays

I am trying to write this mathematical expression correctly and systematically. I need some help, please:

```latex
\begin{equation} \label{58}
\begin{array}{l}
\alpha_{\mathcal{A}}\|w_n-w_n^{hk}\|^2_V \\
&\leq \langle \mathcal{A}\varepsilon(w_n)-\mathcal{A}^l\varepsilon(w_n^{hk}),\varepsilon(w_n-v_n^h) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}+ \langle\mathcal{A}^l\varepsilon(w_n),\varepsilon(v_n^h-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} +\langle F_n,w_n-v_n^h\rangle_V\\
&+ \langle\mathcal{B}^l(\varepsilon(u_n)),\varepsilon(w_n^{hk}-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} + \langle\mathcal{B}^l(\varepsilon(u_n^{hk})),\varepsilon(v_n^h -w_n^{hk})\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} +\langle\int_{0}^t \mathcal{G}^l(t-s)u_n \mathrm{d}s,\varepsilon(w_n^{hk}-
w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}  \\

& + \langle\int_{0}^t \mathcal{G}^l(t-s)u_n^{hk}\mathrm{d}s,\varepsilon(v_n^h-w_n^{hk})\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} +
\langle(\mathcal{P^*})^l\nabla \varphi_n,\varepsilon(w_n^{hk}-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} + \langle(\mathcal{P^*})^l\nabla \varphi_n^{hk},\varepsilon(v_n^h-w_n^{hk})\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}  \\

&-\langle \mathcal{C}^l\theta_n,\varepsilon(w_n^{hk}-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}- \langle \mathcal{C}^l\theta_n^{hk},\varepsilon(v_n^h-w_n^{hk})\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} +
 \int_{\Gamma_3} j_{\nu}^0(w_{n\nu};w_{n\nu}^{hk}-w_{n\nu})+j_\nu^0(w_{n\nu}^{hk};v_{n\nu}^h-w_{n\nu}^{hk}) \mathrm{d}a  \\  
 
&+\int_{\Gamma_3} j_{\tau}^0(w_{n\tau};w_{n\nu}^{hk}-w_{n\nu})+j_\tau^0(w_{n\tau}^{hk};v_{n\nu}^h-w_{n\nu}^{hk}) \mathrm{d}s  \\
&\leq \langle \mathcal{A}^l\varepsilon(w_n)-\mathcal{A}^l\varepsilon(w_n^{hk}),\varepsilon(w_n-v_n^h) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}   +\langle\mathcal{A}^l\varepsilon(w_n),\varepsilon(v_n^h-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} + \langle\mathcal{B}^l(\varepsilon(u_n^{hk})),\varepsilon(v_n^h-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \\

&+ \langle\mathcal{B}^l(\varepsilon(u_n)) -\mathcal{B}^l(\varepsilon(u_n^{hk}))  ,\varepsilon(w_n^{hk} -w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} +\langle\int_{0}^t \mathcal{G}^l(t-s)u_n^{hk} \mathrm{d}s,\varepsilon(v_n^h-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \\

&+ \langle\int_{0}^t \mathcal{G}^l(t-s)u_n \mathrm{d}s-\int_{0}^t \mathcal{G}^l(t-s)u_n^{hk} \mathrm{d}s,\varepsilon(w_n^{hk}-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}+ \langle(\mathcal{P^*})^l\nabla \varphi_n -( \mathcal{P^*})^l\nabla \varphi_n^{hk},\varepsilon(w_n^{hk}-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}\\

&+ \langle(\mathcal{P^*})^l\nabla \varphi_n^{hk},\varepsilon(v_n^h-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} - \langle \mathcal{C}^l\theta_n^{hk},\varepsilon(v_n^h-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} -\langle \mathcal{C}^l\theta_n- \mathcal{C}^l\theta_n^{hk},\varepsilon(w_n^{hk}-w_n)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \\

&+ \langle F_n,w_n-v_n^h\rangle_V + 
\int_{\Gamma_3} j_{\nu}^0(w_{n\nu};w_{n\nu}^{hk}-w_{n\nu})+j_\nu^0(w_{n\nu}^{hk};v_{n\nu}^h-w_{n\nu}^{hk}) \mathrm{d}a \\

&+\int_{\Gamma_3} j_{\tau}^0(w_{n\tau};w_{n\nu}^{hk}-w_{n\nu})+j_\tau^0(w_{n\tau}^{hk};v_{n\nu}^h-w_{n\nu}^{hk}) \mathrm{d}a \\

&+
\int_{\Gamma_3} j_{\nu}^0(w_{n\nu}^{hk};v_n^h-w_n) \mathrm{d}a + j_\tau^0(w_{n\tau}^{hk};v_n^h-w_{n\nu}) \mathrm{d}a
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: You've defined an `array` with one `l`eft aligned column, but you are using more than one column. If suggest to use `split` instead of an `array`. See the `amsmath` manual for more information.

Comment: Have you considered using landscape mode equation? it might be easier to read.

Comment: Note that blank lines aren't allowed in display environments.